# Is there a way to not show questions that have already been closed?

Tags: support, search, closed-questions

Is there anything that I can enter into the Search box to automatically filter out closed questions so that they don't appear in the search results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`closed:0`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search#advanced-search)

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept later, MSO doesn't allow me to accept it now :(

Comment: That was quick, had to wait until now to accept the answer :) Is there a list of these parameters/keywords that can be entered into the search box?

Comment: Yeah, just click above [`closed:0`](http://stackoverflow.com/search#advanced-search) text, there is a link attach to it.